# orderBy case insensitive with Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent (Laravel 5.4) and a postgreSQL database. I created a `users` table with a `name` string column. Running this code returns users ordered by name BUT the search is case-sensitive:

```
$users = \App\User::orderBy('name')->get();
```

This code returns something like:

```
Alix
Beatrice
Zorro
adam
bill
```

Is there a way to get this list case-insensitive. I would like to have something like:

```
adam
Alix
Beatrice
bill
Zorro
```

Is there a way to get a "case-insensitive order by" result ?

*My question is about `orderBy` and Eloquent, not `sortBy` and Collections.*

Comment: From where you are performing search?

Comment: This isn't a Laraval issue, it's a PostgreSQL issue.  PostgreSQL is doing the ordering.  Hint: It is possible to order in PostgreSQL based on a function applied to a field's value.  For example `ORDER BY UPPER(field_name_goes_here)` is a perfectly valid sorting strategy

Comment: @schellingerht Thanks. Not a duplicate of this one though. My question is about `orderBy` and Eloquent, not `sortBy` and Collections.

Comment: @schellingerht could you remove your misleading duplicate flag?

Comment: Excuse me, it was about the answer of @Rahul. Removed flag and upvoted your question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**1. Why are you getting this result?**

It is actually your database's collation which determines how strings are compared and ordered.

Probably your current (table) collation is a case-sensitive one. In Postgres, this collation is probably 'C' or 'POSIX'. This implies that `App\User::where('name', 'aDaM')->first();` does NOT retrieve *adam*'s entry and `App\User::orderBy('name')->get();` yields the user names in a case-sensitive alphabetic order. You need a case-insensitive collation in order to have the opposite results. In Postgres, an example of such a collation is en_US.UTF8 (in case your encoding is UTF8).

**2. Possible solutions**

**(1)** Just put your query result in case-insensitive order (in Laravel)

```
App\User::orderBy('name')->get()->sortBy('name', SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Since Laravel 5.3, Eloquent's `get()` returns a Collection.

**(2)** Write a raw SQL query specifying the collation (in Laravel), for example

```
DB::select('select name from users order by name COLLATE "en_US.utf8"');
```

This statement returns an array.

**(3)** Choose another collation for your database. This solution will avoid similar problems in the future.

When you are in a dev situation and working with Laravel's Migrations and Seeders the best solution is to

- delete the database
- create the database again, with the right collation
- run the migrations and seeders

When you are in an other dev situation, you can

- export the database to a dump file (use the create option)
- replace any reference to the old collation by a refence to the new one in the dump file (text editor > find & replace)
- delete the database
- import the dump file

Note that you can change the collations on a running database as well, but be prepared for databases as well as tables as well as columns having (default) collation settings and for problems with indices.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do this as:

```
$orderClause = 'UPPER('.colname.') ASC';
App\User::orderByRaw($orderClause);
```

Comment: Or, to match the OP: `$users = \App\User::orderByRaw('UPPER(name)')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

`SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE` does not go by `orderBy` it goes with `sortBy` on collections, case insensitive `orderBy` isn't an Eloquent behavior it is better to build your SQL query directly on database

Answer (score 0):

Use this: Laravel version 7.x (Worked in MySQL)

```
Institute::where('scholarshipTypeValueId',$valueId)->orderBy('instituteName','ASC')->get()->sortBy('instituteName',SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE)->toJson();
```

or just get in an array use

```
Institute::where('scholarshipTypeValueId',$valueId)->orderBy('instituteName','ASC')->get()->sortBy('instituteName', SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```